# Parsing through nested JSON keys

Tags: python, json, nested

I have a JSON file that looks like this:

```
data = {
    "x": {
        "y": {
            "key": {

            },
            "w": {

            }
}}}
```

And have converted it into a dict in python to them parse through it to look for keys, using the following code:

```
entry = input("Search JSON for the following: ") //search for "key"
if entry in data:
  print(entry)
else:
  print("Not found.")
```

However, even when I input "key" as entry, it still returns "Not found." Do I need to control the depth of data, what if I don't know the location of "key" but still want to search for it.

Comment: Note also the JSON file only has keys, because thats all we need. There are no values equated to each key - could that be the problem?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @AMC - What part of this can't you reproduce from the minimal example?

Comment: @MarkMeyer There is some ambiguity. OP writes that they _have a JSON file that looks like this_, but what they show appears to be a Python dict. The question is also tagged JSON, and it’s mentioned in the title. I think it’s worth clearing things up.

Answer (score 3):

Your method is not working because `key` is not a key in `data`. `data` has one key: `x`. So you need to look at the dictionary and see if the key is in it. If not, you can pass the next level dictionaries back to the function recursively. This will find the *first* matching key:

```
data = {
    "x": {
        "y": {
            "key": "some value",
            "w": {}
}}}

key = "key"

def findValue(key, d):
    if key in d:
        return d[key]
    for v in d.values():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            found = findValue(key, v)
            if found is not None:
                return found

findValue(key, data)  
# 'some value'
```

It will return `None` if your key is not found

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach which allows you to collect all the values from a nested dict, if the keys are repeated at different levels of nesting. It's very similar to the above answer, just wrapped in a function with a nonlocal list to hold the results:

```
def foo(mydict, mykey):
    result = []
    num_recursive_calls = 0

    def explore(mydict, mykey):
        #nonlocal result      #allow successive recursive calls to write to list
                              #actually this is unnecessary in this case! Here 
                              #is where we would need it, for a call counter: 
        nonlocal num_recursive_calls
        num_recursive_calls += 1
        for key in mydict.keys():   #get all keys from that level of nesting
            if mykey == key:
                print(f"Found {key}")
                result.append({key:mydict[key]})

            elif isinstance(mydict.get(key), dict):
                print(f"Found nested dict under {key}, exploring")
                explore(mydict[key], mykey)

    explore(mydict, mykey)
    print(f"explore called {num_recursive_calls} times") #see above
    return result
```

For example, with

```
data = {'x': {'y': {'key': {}, 'w': {}}}, 'key': 'duplicate'}
```

This will return:

```
[{'key': {}}, {'key': 'duplicate'}]
```

Comment: I said the same thing above but i'll say it again: I am new to stackoverflow so I'm a little speechless at how quickly and willing people are to help. thank you again! I actually used your code specifically and it worked beautifully.

Comment: Thanks, actually I just realized that nonlocal is not needed for inner function to be able to write into the list, it's only needed for variables.  Very odd, I put in an example (and that's why answering questions here is so useful, I'm always learning new things this way, now I'll remember when nonlocal is needed).

Comment: Yea actually when I run your code it doesn't work for some cases. Should i change the nonlocal part of it?

Comment: @bguan2020 The nonlocal declaration should be removable with no problems. Where this code might fail, for example if the value in a key-value pair is a list of dicts, or a tuple of dicts, it won't go into that data structure to look for more dicts, i.e. ```{ 'a': [ {'key':1}]}``` would not work.... And it will also fail to search through nested dicts under the target, i.e. ```{ 'key' : { {'key': x} }``` since it stops when the target is found. These can likely be fixed with more complex code...